# how to write a regular expression to return the keyword in the url?

Tags: python, regex

we want to write a regular expression to query the url based on some keywords

for example, when we input 'google'. the regular express should help us to find the urls as:

https://www.google.com

https://api.google.com/help

https://www.apigoogle.com/example/02.js

https://www.googleapi.com/02/example/02.js

Currently my Regex is, 'sites' is the input value:

**^http(s)?://([a-z0-9-]+.)+(" + sites + ").(com|net)/?$**

It only matches the first one, how can I finish my Regex...?

Comment: As of now you could easily use `if 'google' in ...`, so what is your actual use case?

Comment: What if you drop the last dollar-sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose is to check if keyword inside domain part.

1. `^(http\w?.{3})` start with two kinds of protocol
2. `([^\/]*?google[^\/]*?)` check whether domain part has keyword. To avoid matching more than the specified area, did not match `\`
3. `(?=\/|$)` the main part should be end of text, or it has `\` behind

Code:

```
import re


regex = lambda keyword: r"^(http\w?.{3})([^\/]*?%s[^\/]*?)(?=\/|$)"%keyword

text = """
https://www.google.com

https://api.google.com/help

https://www.apigoogle.com/example/02.js

https://www.googleapi.com/02/example/02.js

https://www.abcd.com/red?=www.google.com

https://www.googleapi.com/02/example/03.js
"""

for e in text.split():
    if re.search(regex("google"),e):
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you.

```
^((https)\:\/\/)(([a-z0-9])+\.)*(google|apigoogle\.com)
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/a6yNig/1)

Comment: This regex wont pass the 4th url